# Create File From Azure Data Lake Store .NET SDK

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I can't find any refrence in documentation about that. My question is simple, how to create file in data lake store from .net sdk ( for example create test.csv in path /Test/test.csv ). Is there any way to do this, or moreover create file from byte or string content ( some other upload parameter class which first argument is not path to source file, but content which i want send to data lake store ).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the reference article that explains how to create a file: [FileSystemOperationsExtensions.Create Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datalake.store.filesystemoperationsextensions.create?view=azuremgmtdatalakestore-2.1.0-preview#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataLake_Store_FileSystemOperationsExtensions_Create_Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataLake_Store_IFileSystemOperations_System_String_System_String_System_IO_Stream_System_Nullable_System_Boolean__System_Nullable_Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataLake_Store_Models_SyncFlag__)

If you have not already seen it, this is a good starting point on the .NET SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk

Comment: Could you please give me an example?